# startActivity() or any other suggestions?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

In my apps menu class I want a button to start an activity. This doesn't work with the StartActivity() method becaue it's not a subclass to Activity at all. So how should I do?

If you have read the "Beginning Android Games" you can see in the 6th chapter when he do a snake game how its shold look like when I want to start an activity.

//Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either pass your context with the constructor like below or pass it into a static method:

```
 private Context context;

 public MenuClass(Context context){
     this.context = context;
 }

 private void someMethod(){
     // Do your stuff
     startNextActivity();
 }

 private void startNextActivity(){
      context.startActivity(context, OtherClass.class);
 }
```

Static method:

```
 public static void startNextActivity(Context context){
      context.startActivity(context, OtherClass.class);
 }

 // Use
 MenuClass.startNextActivity(someContext);
```

Comment: I have no Context in the constructor.

Comment: Make a constructor with that signature. You can make any constructor you want in your own classes!

Comment: I fixed it, it was because of you guys, thank you!
I added a context in all the constructus I had.

Comment: Changing constructors to take in variables that you need is a big step forward. Always remember you can do that. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. And when I look at your static method that you have done, does it work on any subclass?

Comment: Yes, it's static so it's not part of a Class instance. You might want to read up on statics

Comment: I know what it do, but I didn't know that it works if you use it in another subclass :)

Answer (score 2):

Are you using an intent?

```
Intent it = new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
startActivity(it);
```

Pass the context to that class and call startActivity with the intent.

```
 Intent it = new Intent(firstActivity.this, secondActivity.class);
 context.startActivity(it);
```

Comment: See my edit, you should call it on a Context object. You should get it passed from elsewhere to use it.

Comment: I have no context in the view so that does now work eather :(

Comment: In one or another way, you gave to start the activity from a certain context. the View that you have is also launched in a context so directly or indirectly you will need the context.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Context.startActivity()` if you are launching from a class that is not an Activity.

Comment: But the method startActivity is not a static one, so it doesn't work.

Comment: dtmilano means 'Context' here as an instance of the type context

Comment: I fixed it, it was because of you guys, thank you!
I added a context in all the constructus I had.